# Install openstack newton even though it is EOL?

Tags: openstack

Any way I can install OpenStack Newton now? I know its EOL and the code is not available on the upstream repos. Reason I am asking for Newton is to perform some tests with a set of drivers on this particular environment. No problem getting O, P, Q or master version of OpenStack setup. Just wanted to see if there was a way of installing N using devstack/packstack/any other means possible.

Answer (score 1):

It should still be possible to install Newton. You are probably best of deploying using a tool like packstack, but should in theory work using devstack as well.

Newton no longer has a stable branch, but you can always access the last version of newton using the newton-eol tag, e.g. for nova [here](https://github.com/openstack/nova/tree/newton-eol).

If you decide to pip install a Newton service it's important to use the upper-constraints to make sure the libraries installed are compatible with Newton.

> pip install -c https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=newton-eol package-name==package-version